# Heroku Procfile declares types -> (none)

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn, procfile

I already change the name correctly to Procfile with capital P but the problem still occurs.

this is what Heroku says in the terminal:

[image: heroku terminal]

here is my project:

[image: my file directory]

and here is the code in Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app_with_handler.py:app --log-file -
```

did I miss something or are there anything I should try next?

Comment: try by removing `:app`

Comment: tried it, still result in `Procfile declares types -> (none)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: solve the problem by deleting the Procfile, commit, and push to heroku. Then create the same exact Procfile again, commit and push to heroku again. This way seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you **did not push** Procfile and changes to your git repository.

Before you deploy your app with chages on Heroku using "git push heroku main" command, you should push your changes to git repository first as Win Wongsawatdichart describe above.